# Response from server not arriving c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sockets

I am trying to create http server. Currently on windows i have found few materials which lead to this code

```
using namespace std;
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8080"

int __cdecl main(void)
{

    std::stringstream wsss;
    wsss << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: 5\r\n"
        << "Ahoj\r\n";
    string tmp = wsss.str();
    const char * cstr = tmp.c_str();

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    cout << "Starting to listen " << endl;
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Listening " << endl;
    // No longer need server socket
    //closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            cout << recvbuf << endl;
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, cstr , iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
            cout << " === " << endl;
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("Connection closing11...\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);


    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

However, when i try to use postman, it does write
"Start to listen"
"Listening"
Displays get request
Bytes sent: 431

and after that it goes on halt. The client does not recieve  anything thus the server is still on ( should shut down after 1 connection ).

I keep failing to find the reason why it would behave like this w/e any error.
I am usin Visual Studio 2015.
All help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://samuel-beckett.net/Waiting_for_Godot_Part1.html

Comment: please create a [MCVE] emphasis on **minimal**

Comment: I don't understand why you are expecting a single application running in a single thread and using blocking calls to act as both a server and its client.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy My client is simulated in postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

- Your HTTP response is formatted wrong:
- your `Content-Type` header is malformed.
- your `Content-Length` header should be `4` (or `6`) instead of `5`.
- you are missing an additional required `\r\n` after `Content-Length: ...\r\n`
  and before `Ahoj`.  HTTP headers are terminated by `\r\n\r\n`.
- the `\r\n` after `Ahoj` needs to be removed, unless you increase the `Content-Length` to 6.
- HTTP keep-alives are negotiated, so DO NOT blindly include a `Connection: keep-alive` header in your response.  You must check if the client sends an HTTP 1.0 request with a `Connection: keep-alive` header, or an HTTP 1.1 request without a `Connection: close` header, and then act accordingly.  DO NOT keep the connection alive unless the client asks you to do so, and you agree to do so.  Be sure to set the `Connection` response header accordingly to what you actually do with the socket.
- You are not handling client requests correctly.

First, `recv()` does not return null-terminated data, but your `cout` statement assumes it does. You need to limit the output to the actual number of bytes reported by `recv()`.  Use `cout.write()` for that instead of using `cout << ...`.

But, more importantly, you are not actually parsing the client's HTTP requests at all.  When the client sends *any* arbitrary data (not a valid HTTP request), you are trying to send your HTTP response, but you are setting the `len` parameter of `send()` to the number of bytes you read from the client, not the number of bytes of your response.

You MUST parse the client's requests correctly!  Especially if you honor keep-alives.  Start by reading the initial request line, which tells you the resource being requested, and the HTTP version being requested.  Then, read the request headers, line-by-line, until you encounter the `\r\n\r\n` sequence that ends the headers.  Then you must parse the headers to determine IF a request body is present, HOW to read it, and WHEN to stop reading it.  Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for specific details about that.

After you have read the ENTIRE request in full and validated it, THEN send your response (making sure to set the `Connection` response header accordingly), and then close the socket if a keep-alive was not requested, otherwise loop back to the beginning and wait for the next request to arrive.

- `send()` can send fewer bytes than requested, so you need to check the return value and call `send()` again if there is still more data to send.  You need to call `send()` in a loop until the entire response has been sent in full.
- *"Echo the buffer back to the sender"* is not the right thing for an HTTP server to do.  It feels like you took an ECHO server example and are modifying it for HTTP.  HTTP is much more complicated to implement than ECHO.

With that said, try something more like this (untested, but should give you an idea of what's involved):

There are many problems with your code.

- Your HTTP response is formatted wrong:
- your `Content-Type` header is malformed.
- your `Content-Length` header should be `4` (or `6`) instead of `5`.
- you are missing an additional required `\r\n` after `Content-Length: ...\r\n`
  and before `Ahoj`.  HTTP headers are terminated by `\r\n\r\n`.
- the `\r\n` after `Ahoj` needs to be removed, unless you increase the `Content-Length` to 6.
- HTTP keep-alives are negotiated, so DO NOT blindly include a `Connection: keep-alive` header in your response.  You must check if the client sends an HTTP 1.0 request with a `Connection: keep-alive` header, or an HTTP 1.1 request without a `Connection: close` header, and then act accordingly.  DO NOT keep the connection alive unless the client asks you to do so, and you agree to do so.  Be sure to set the `Connection` response header accordingly to what you actually do with the socket.
- You are not handling client requests correctly.

First, `recv()` does not return null-terminated data, but your `cout` statement assumes it does. You need to limit the output to the actual number of bytes reported by `recv()`.  Use `cout.write()` for that instead of using `cout << ...`.

But, more importantly, you are not actually parsing the client's HTTP requests at all.  When the client sends *any* arbitrary data (not a valid HTTP request), you are trying to send your HTTP response, but you are setting the `len` parameter of `send()` to the number of bytes you read from the client, not the number of bytes of your response.

You MUST parse the client's requests correctly!  Especially if you honor keep-alives.  Start by reading the initial request line, which tells you the resource being requested, and the HTTP version being requested.  Then, read the request headers, line-by-line, until you encounter the `\r\n\r\n` sequence that ends the headers.  Then you must parse the headers to determine IF a request body is present, HOW to read it, and WHEN to stop reading it.  Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for specific details about that.

After you have read the ENTIRE request in full and validated it, THEN send your response (making sure to set the `Connection` response header accordingly), and then close the socket if a keep-alive was not requested, otherwise loop back to the beginning and wait for the next request to arrive.

- `send()` can send fewer bytes than requested, so you need to check the return value and call `send()` again if there is still more data to send.  You need to call `send()` in a loop until the entire response has been sent in full.
- *"Echo the buffer back to the sender"* is not the right thing for an HTTP server to do.  It feels like you took an ECHO server example and are modifying it for HTTP.  HTTP is much more complicated to implement than ECHO.

With that said, try something more like this (untested, but should give you an idea of what's involved):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8080"

class WinsockError : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    int ErrCode;
    std::string FuncName;

    WinsockError(const char *func)
        : std::runtime_error("Winsock function failed"), ErrCode(WSAGetLastError()), FuncName(func)
    {
    }

    WinsockError(int err, const char *func)
        : std::runtime_error("Winsock function failed"), ErrCode(err), FuncName(func)
    {
    }
};

class WinsockDisconnected : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    bool WasGraceful;

    WinsockDisconnected(bool graceful)
        : std::runtime_error("socket disconnected"), WasGraceful(graceful)
    {
    }
};

class JustStopNow : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    JustStopNow()
        : std::runtime_error("")
    {
    }
};

class WSAInit
{
private:
    WSAInit(const WSAInit &) {}
    WSAInit& operator=(const WSAInit &) { return *this; }

public:
    WSAInit() {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            throw WinsockError(iResult, "WSAStartup");
        }
    }

    ~WSAInit() {
        WSACleanup();
    }
};

class Socket
{
private:
    SOCKET m_sock;

    Socket(const Socket &) {}
    Socket& operator=(const Socket &) { return *this; }

public:
    Socket(SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET) : m_sock(s) {}

    ~Socket() {
        Close();
    }

    void Close() {
        if (m_sock != INVALID_SOCKET) {
            shutdown(m_sock, SD_BOTH);
            closesocket(m_sock);
            m_sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    operator SOCKET () {
        return m_sock;
    }

    bool operator !() {
        return (m_sock == INVALID_SOCKET);
    }

    Socket& operator =(SOCKET s) {
        if (m_sock != s) {
            close();
            m_sock = s;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    int ReadSome(void *buffer, int buflen)
    {
        int iResult = recv(m_sock, buffer, buflen, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            switch (iResult) {
                case WSAECONNABORTED:
                case WSAECONNRESET:
                case WSAENETRESET:
                    throw WinsockDisconnected(false);
            }
            throw WinsockError(iResult, "recv");
        }

        if (iResult == 0) {
            throw WinsockDisconnected(true);
        }

        std::cout << "Bytes received: " << iResult << std:::endl;
        std::cout.write((char*)recvbuf, iResult);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        return iResult;
    }

    void ReadAll(void *buffer, int buflen)
    {
        unsigned char *pbuffer = (unsigned char *) buffer;
        int iResult;

        while (buflen > 0) {
            iResult = ReadSome(pbuffer, buflen);
            pbuffer += iResult;
            buflen -= iResult;
        }
    }

    void Send(const std:string &s)
    {
        Send(s.c_str(), s.size());
    }

    void Send(const void *buffer, int buflen)
    {
        const unsigned char *pbuffer = (const unsigned char *) buffer;
        int iResult;

        while (buflen > 0) {
            iResult = send(m_sock, pbuffer, buflen, 0);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                switch (iResult) {
                    case WSAECONNABORTED:
                    case WSAECONNRESET:
                    case WSAENETRESET:
                        throw WinsockDisconnected(false);
                }
                throw WinsockError(iResult, "send");
            }

            std::cout << "Bytes send: " << iResult << std:::endl;
            std::cout.write((char*)pbuffer, iResult);
            std::cout << std::endl;

            pbuffer += iResult;
            buflen -= iResult;
        }
    }
};

class AddrInfoPtr
{
private:
    struct addrinfo *m_info;

    AddrInfoPtr(const AddrInfoPtr &) {}
    AddrInfoPtr& operator=(const AddrInfoPtr &) { return *this; }

public:
    AddrInfoPtr(struct addrinfo *info = NULL) : m_info(info) {}

    ~AddrInfoPtr() {
        if (m_info) {
            freeaddrinfo(m_info);
        }
    }

    operator struct addrinfo* () {
        return m_info;
    }

    struct addrinfo* operator ->() {
        return m_info;
    }

    bool operator !() {
        return (m_info == NULL);
    }

    struct addrinfo** operator & {
        return &m_info;
    }
};

char UpperCaseChar(char ch)
{
    return std::toupper(ch);
}

void UpperCaseStr(std::string &s)
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), UpperCaseChar);
}

void LTrimLWS(std::string &s)
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(" \t"));
}

void RTrimLWS(std::string &s)
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(" \t")+1);
}

void TrimLWS(std::string &s)
{
    LTrimLWS(s);
    RTrimLWS(s);
}

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> NameValueMap;
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> ByteVec;

class InputBuffer
{
private:
    Socket &m_sock;
    ByteVec m_buf;

    static void ParseHeader(const std::string &header, NameValueMap &headers)
    {
        if (header.empty()) {
            return;
        }

        std::string name, value;
        std::istringstream iss(header);

        std::getline(iss, name, ':');
        TrimLWS(name);

        std::getline(iss, value);
        TrimLWS(value);

        UpperCaseStr(name);

        NameValueMap::iterator iter = headers.find(name);
        if (iter != headers.end())
            iter->second += ("," + value);
        else
            headers.insert(std::make_pair(name, value));
    }

public:
    InputBuffer(Socket &s) : m_sock(s) {}

    bool HasPendingData()
    {
        return !m_buf.empty();
    }

    bool FillFromSocket(int Timeout = -1)
    {
        if (Timeout >= 0) {
            fd_set rfd;
            FD_ZERO(&rfd);
            FD_SET(m_sock, &rfd);

            timeval t;
            t.tv_sec = Timeout / 1000;
            t.tv_usec = (Timeout % 1000) * 1000;

            switch (select(0, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &t)) {
                case SOCKET_ERROR:
                    throw WinsockError("select");
                case 0:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        unsigned char buf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

        int iResult = m_sock.ReadSome(buf, sizeof buf);
        m_buf.insert(m_buf.end(), &buf[0], &buf[iResult]);

        return true;
    }

    std::string ReadLine()
    {
        ByteVec::iterator iter = std::find(m_buf.begin(), m_buf.end(), '\n');
        while (iter == m_buf.end()) {
            ByteVec::size_type offset = m_buf.size();
            FillFromSocket();
            iter = std::find(m_buf.begin()+offset, m_buf.end(), '\n');
        }

        std::string::size_type len = std::distance(m_buf.begin(), iter);
        if ((len > 0) && (*(iter-1) == '\r')) {
            --len;
        }

        std::string out(m_buf.begin(), m_buf.begin()+len);
        m_buf.erase(m_buf.begin(), iter+1);

        return out;
    }

    void ReadHeaders(NameValueMap &headers)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ostringstream oss;

        do {
            line = ReadLine();
            if (line.empty()) {
                break;
            }

            if ((line[0] == ' ') || (line[0] == '\t')) {
                LTrimLWS(line);
                oss << ' ' << line;
            }
            else {
                ParseHeader(oss.str(), headers);
                RTrimLWS(line);
                oss.str(line);
            }
        }
        while (true);

        ParseHeader(oss.str(), headers);
    }

    void Read(void *buffer, int buflen)
    {
        unsigned char *pbuffer = (unsigned char *) buffer;

        while (buflen > 0) {
            if (m_buf.empty()) {
                FillFromSocket();
            }

            ByteVec::size_type len = std::max(m_buf.size(), buflen);
            ByteVec::iterator start = m_buf.begin();
            ByteVec::iterator finish = start+len;

            std::copy(start, finish, pbuffer);
            m_buf.erase(start, finish);

            pbuffer += len;
            buflen -= len;
        }
    }
};

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    try {
        // Initialize Winsock
        TWSAInit wsa;

        // Resolve the server address and port

        Socket ListenSocket;

        {
        struct addrinfo hints;
        AddrInfoPtr result;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            throw WinsockError(iResult, "getaddrinfo");
        }

        // Create a TCP listening socket

        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (!ListenSocket) {
            throw WinsockError("socket");
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket

        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            throw WinsockError("bind");
        }

        }

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            throw WinsockError("listen");

        std::cout << "Listening" << std::endl;

        do {
            // Accept a client socket

            Socket ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
            if (!ClientSocket) {
                throw WinsockError("accept");
            }

            std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;

            // TODO: move the following to a thread so you can
            // service multiple clients at the same time...

            try {
                // read HTTP requests until disconnect

                InputBuffer io(ClientSocket);
                bool keepAlive;

                do {
                    std::string line, value;
                    std::string method, resource;
                    int majorVersion, minorVersion;
                    NameValueMap headers;
                    ByteVec body;
                    std::ostringstream response;

                    line = io.ReadLine();

                    // parse request line

                    {
                    std::istringstream iss(line);
                    std::getline(iss, method, ' ');
                    UpperCaseStr(method);
                    std::getline(iss, resource, ' ');
                    std::getline(iss, value);
                    }

                    {
                    std::istringstream iss(value);
                    std::getline(iss, value, '/');
                    char dot;

                    if ((value != "HTTP") ||
                        !(iss >> majorVersion >> dot >> minorVersion) ||
                        (dot != '.')) {
                        response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                 << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                 << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                 << "\r\n";
                        ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                        throw JustStopNow();
                    }
                    }

                    // read request headers

                    io.ReadHeaders(headers);

                    // HTTP 1.1+ requires a "Host" header

                    if (
                        (majorVersion > 1) ||
                        ((majorVersion == 1) && (minorVersion >= 1))
                        ) {
                        if (headers["HOST"].empty()) {
                            response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                     << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                     << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                     << "\r\n";
                            ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                            throw JustStopNow();
                        }
                    }

                    // check if client wants a 100 response before it sends the request body

                    value = headers["EXPECT"];
                    UpperCaseStr(value);

                    if (value.find("100-CONTINUE") != std::string::npos) {
                        if (!io.HasPendingData()) {
                            if (!io.FillFromSocket(0)) {
                                ClientSocket.Send("HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // determine if any body is being sent, and if so then read it

                    value = headers["TRANSFER-ENCODING"];
                    UpperCaseStr(value);

                    if ((!value.empty()) && (value != "IDENTITY")) {
                        do {
                            line = io.ReadLine();

                            std::istringstream iss(line);
                            ByteVec::size_type size = 0;
                            if (!(iss >> std::hex >> size)) {
                                response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                         << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                         << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                         << "\r\n";
                                ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                                throw JustStopNow();
                            }

                            if (size > 0) {
                                ByteVec::size_type offset = body.size();
                                body.resize(offset+size);
                                io.Read(&body[offset], size);
                                io.ReadLine();
                            }
                            else if (size == 0) {
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                         << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                         << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                         << "\r\n";
                                ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                                throw JustStopNow();
                            }
                        }
                        while (true);

                        io.ReadHeaders(headers);
                    }
                    else {
                        value = headers["CONTENT-LENGTH"];
                        if (!value.empty()) {
                            std::istringstream iss(value);
                            ByteVec::size_type size = 0;
                            if (!(iss >> size)) {
                                response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                         << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                         << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                         << "\r\n";
                                ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                                throw JustStopNow();
                            }

                            if (size > 0) {
                                body.resize(size);
                                io.Read(&body[0], size);
                            }
                            else if (size != 0) {
                                response << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                                         << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                         << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                         << "\r\n";
                                ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                                throw JustStopNow();
                            }
                        }
                        else if ((method == "POST") || (method == "PUT")) {
                            response << "HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required\r\n"
                                     << "Connection: close\r\n"
                                     << "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
                                     << "\r\n";
                            ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                            throw JustStopNow();
                        }
                    }

                    // determine if a keep-alive is requested

                    value = headers["CONNECTION"];
                    UpperCaseStr(value);

                    keepAlive = (
                        (majorVersion > 1) ||
                        ((majorVersion == 1) && (minorVersion >= 1))
                        )
                        ? (value != "CLOSE")
                        : (value == "KEEP-ALIVE");

                    // process method, resource, headers, and body as needed

                    response << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
                             << "Connection: " << (keepAlive ? "keep-alive" : "close") << "\r\n"
                             << "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                             << "Content-Length: 4\r\n"
                             << "\r\n"
                             << "Ahoj";
                    ClientSocket.Send(response.str());
                }
                while (keepAlive);
            }
            catch (const JustStopNow &) {
            }
            catch (const WinsockDisconnected &e) {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected " << e.WasGraceful ? "gracefully" : "abnormally" << std::endl;
            }
            catch (const WinsockError &e) {
                std::cerr << "Client disconnected because " << e.FuncName << " failed with error: " << e.ErrCode << std::endl;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
    catch (const WinsockError &e) {
        std::cerr << e.FuncName << " failed with error: " << e.ErrCode << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do realize i do not parse client request but thats on purpose. My initial goal was to just send response and after that play around with requests. But your answer is great, thank you.